# JAVA miglayout way to set and get text to/from cell

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I'm creating a Pac-man game in which I would like to use miglayout with a text file to set/get text out of cell. I have map (32x32) let's say. And I want to fill every cell with `W` (ok that is not a problem, I can create a function which every time is called creates new JLable and `add` it to the cell).

FUNCTION:

```
public void function(String rowColumn){
    JLabel lblH = new JLabel("W");
    contentPane.add(lblH, "cell " + rowColumn);
}
```

But then I can't read it.

Question: How do I read and write text in the cell?

EDIT: Or, is there any better layout which has cells and can set/get text from/to a cell?

Comment: For read/write to the `JPanels` after, you can add them into a List after creation.

Comment: And why don't you just draw matrix of squares on a single `JPanel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this:

```
public static void start(){
    for(int a = 0; a <= 22; a++){
        for(int b = 0; b <= 37; b++){
            printToCell(String.valueOf(b), String.valueOf(a), "H");
        }
    }
}


public static void clearContentPane(){
    engine_design.Engine.contentPane.removeAll();
    engine_design.Engine.contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "", ""));
}


public static void printToCell(String column, String row, String letter){
    JLabel lblH = new JLabel(letter);
    lblH.setFont(new Font(lblH.getName(), Font.BOLD, 15));
    engine_design.Engine.contentPane.add(lblH, "cell " + column + " " + row);

}
```

And for the reading I will use list, how someones mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

Layout managers are meant for laying out components.

You should keep references to components which you intend to use after you lay them out. In your case it should be probably a matrix-style data structure in which you store references to labels like `JLabel[][]` or `List<List<JLabel>>` or whatever suits your use cases best.

Then, provided `x` and `y` coordinates, just write/read the text to/from the desired label:

`cells[x][y].getText() // Array`

or

`cells.get(x).get(y).getText() // List`

or

... // Your data structure

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment. There is no need to use multiple `JComponents` and `MigLayout`. You can just use graphics and draw cells as shown in this demo:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class GraphicsDemo {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                World world = new World();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
                frame.add(world);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                // frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

    static class World extends JPanel {

        public static final int SQUARE_SIZE = 48;
        public static final int CELL_SIZE = 50;

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            for (int j = 0; j < getPreferredSize().getHeight() / CELL_SIZE; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < getPreferredSize().getWidth() / CELL_SIZE; i++) {
                    g.fillRect(i * CELL_SIZE, j * CELL_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(350, 250);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]